# Google SDK missing access token

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to automate process via Jenkins, for creating and deleting users in G-Suite via API.
I could generate API Key, OAuth 2.0 Cliend ID & Client Secret, but from this page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing.html?authuser=1
i understand, that i need to get access token.
So i can't find any place where can i can access token or refresh token and how to request it, anyone who succeeded in this?

Comment: The process should be automatic, without any user intervention

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a token using JWT and impersonate an admin (not sure if super admin) in order to be able to create Users in G Suite

[Check the JWT documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Hope it helps!

Comment: i tried using JWT - it's says invalid credentials, so i tried from link above, to use "service_account", and get an error:

**`AttributeError: module 'google.oauth2.service_account' has no attribute 'Credentials'`**

any ideas?